# The specified value "07/24/2020" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd". angular

Tags: html, angular, ngx-bootstrap

Hi Guys I am using bsdatepicker input type = "date" this is my requirement, while i am clicking on dates on calendar I am facing this issue

The specified value "07/24/2020" does not conform to the required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Comment: What do you mean by "does not confirm to the required format"? Can you elaborate or provide an example please.

Comment: Just quickly glancing at the **documentation** for bsDatePicker shows that **you can DEFINE** the date format you get back from it: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#format

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the example you've given, your date format seems to be "MM/dd/yyyy"
You can specify that in the [bsConfig] attribute of the datepicker

```
<input
    class="form-control"
    bsDatepicker
    [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'MM/DD/YYYY' }">
</div>
```